# display error messages for copy process in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i need some help for display error messages in my copy batch. I have following script.
Now i want that the batch show me the names of the computer, where the copying process was successful and also the names where not.
The computer_names.txt containes the names writenn down in each row like
\\pc_name1

```
@echo off

call :isAdmin

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
goto :run
) else (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto :UACPrompt
)

exit /b

:isAdmin
fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% >nul
exit /b

:run


set frompath= "\\server01\path01\file01.txt"
for /f "eol= tokens=1" %%i in (\\server01\path01\computer_names.txt) do copy /v /y %frompath% "%%i\server02\path02"



exit /b

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %~1", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B`
```

Comment: my problem is,the syntax for the pc's from the file! if %errorlevel% 1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `errorlevel` more or less like this (on mobile, so unable to test)

```
for /f "eol= tokens=1" %%i in (\\server01\path01\computer_names.txt) do (
    copy /v /y %frompath% "%%i\server02\path02"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
         echo %%i Success
    ) else (
         echo %%i Failed
 )
)
```

Comment: i already did this but i need a message with the computer name where it wasn't possible to copy or wehere it was possible like \\pc_name success

Comment: sorry my fault. fi forgot a bracket